# Is possible to insert a Header in iPad split view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uisplitviewcontroller

In iOS the splitView controller seems to work only in full screen.
There is a way to set the height of the master/detail controller to make space for a top view (like a header)?  [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUtJj.png)

I could make the layout manually but I will loose the functionality of the master/detail controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a custom header view, The example mentioned has a custom navigation bar, I think you should implement that.

Comment: Solved embedding the split view controller into a container view.

Comment: @Danilo Can you please share it how you have done this ?

Comment: I embedded the Master-Detail view into a Container View: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/creating_a_custom_container_view_controller